# Resize SVG by changes in path

Tags: css, svg

So I have a width and height of container and viewBox, can't change these things
Only thing I can do is send this component a path

For now the SVG is now adjusting in it's container due to the size being too big

Can I change the aspect ratio / size of SVG via the path ?

Sample Code

```
<svg viewBox="-2 -3 24 24" width="30px" height="30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"><path fill="#3E3E3E" d="M18.438 19.102a11 11 0 0 1-18.4-7.184c-.042-.504.372-.915.878-.915.507 0 .912.411.963.915a9.16 9.16 0 0 0 5.793 7.623A9.168 9.168 0 0 0 17.749 17.2h-2.663a.917.917 0 1 1 0-1.832h4.269a.917.917 0 0 1 .916.916v4.264a.916.916 0 0 1-1.833 0V19.1v.002ZM4.248 4.807H6.91a.917.917 0 1 1 0 1.832H2.64a.917.917 0 0 1-.917-.916V1.455a.916.916 0 0 1 1.833 0v1.448a11 11 0 0 1 18.407 7.184c.041.505-.373.915-.88.915-.505 0-.911-.411-.962-.915a9.161 9.161 0 0 0-5.794-7.623A9.168 9.168 0 0 0 4.249 4.807h-.002Z"></path></svg>
```

[image: SVN Render]

Again goal to achieve: make SVG to fit this viewBox and width height.

Comment: can you add other things inside the svg besides a path?

Comment: What do you mean by "path" here? Is it a full <path> element? How do you pass it? As a string? As a DOM element? Or is it just a `d` attribute value? If so, would it replace the one of the current <path> element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. You'd have to change the SVG path to fit the box, but you can't "resize" per-se.

I manually resized your path to fit the box.

```
<path fill="#3E3E3E" d="M1.2 3.3H4a1 1 0 1 1 0 1.8H.6a1 1 0 0 1-.9-.9V0a1 1 0 0 1 1.9 0v1.4A11 11 0 0 1 20 8.6c0 .5-.4.9-1 .9a1 1 0 0 1-.9-1A9.2 9.2 0 0 0 12.3 1a9.2 9.2 0 0 0-10 2.3ZM17.4 16.1A11 11 0 0 1-1 8.9c0-.5.4-.9 1-.9.4 0 .8.4.9 1a9.2 9.2 0 0 0 5.8 7.5 9.2 9.2 0 0 0 10-2.3h-2.6a1 1 0 1 1 0-1.8h4.3a1 1 0 0 1 .9.9v4.2a1 1 0 0 1-1.9 0v-1.4Z"></path>
```

> How I did it:
>
> I used svgomg with precision: 1, to simplify the path to a point where it was small enough for me to actually manually edit.
>
> Then I split it into two separate paths (top and bottom arrows) (using
> the `Z` as the path separator), wrapped them in `<g transform="translate(x, y)"></g>` until it looked right, copied the
> remainder back into svgomg where it is smart enough to convert the
> transforms into a single path.

Comment: May I ask what did you change? Im unable understand much how one can change path as per need

Comment: @Talal_Mirza updated answer with explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `transform` attribute of the `<path>` (using `scale` and `translate`):

```
document.querySelector('path').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.9)')
```

See the snippet for example:

```js
document.querySelector('path').setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.9)')
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-2 -3 24 24" width="30px" height="30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"><path fill="#3E3E3E" d="M18.438 19.102a11 11 0 0 1-18.4-7.184c-.042-.504.372-.915.878-.915.507 0 .912.411.963.915a9.16 9.16 0 0 0 5.793 7.623A9.168 9.168 0 0 0 17.749 17.2h-2.663a.917.917 0 1 1 0-1.832h4.269a.917.917 0 0 1 .916.916v4.264a.916.916 0 0 1-1.833 0V19.1v.002ZM4.248 4.807H6.91a.917.917 0 1 1 0 1.832H2.64a.917.917 0 0 1-.917-.916V1.455a.916.916 0 0 1 1.833 0v1.448a11 11 0 0 1 18.407 7.184c.041.505-.373.915-.88.915-.505 0-.911-.411-.962-.915a9.161 9.161 0 0 0-5.794-7.623A9.168 9.168 0 0 0 4.249 4.807h-.002Z"></path></svg>
```